# Is it possible to bookmark specific URLs within cPanel?

Tags: cpanel

I would ***love*** to be able to bookmark certain cPanel URLs (or send them in an email to other users) however because cPanel embeds a session ID in the URL, I frequently get this error when attempting to access a bookmarked URL:

[image]

I then have to reenter my password, and afterward I am no longer on the page I originally bookmarked.  This seems to happen with phpMyAdmin URLs, AwStats URLs, and numerous other sections within cPanel.

If anyone has found a workaround for this problem, I'd love to know.

Comment: In the example provided, why can't you just bookmark `ames.net.au:2082`?

Comment: @zigojacko He wants to go direct to certain cPanel pages, not the main page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had no problem doing this, providing the session variable is taken out of the bookmarked URL.

It takes me to the login page and then immediately to the page I had bookmarked.

I've frequently used it for the FTP Sessions page on a host that had a tight limit, where I often had to go in just to disconnect all the active sessions.

Your screenshot shows an AWStats URL however, which might behave differently, as it's not a core cPanel page - cPanel just links to it.